# Parametrize fat tailed distributions

Tags: distributions, power-law

I have a empirical distribution with fat tails (i.e. $pdf(x) \sim x^{-\zeta-1}$).

I want to reduce the dimensionality of this object: for any integer $k$, I want a $k-$parametric family of distributions with fat tails. The GB2 family is perfect if $k=4$ but I'd like to find a family for any $k$.

I was thinking of using something like a generalized GB2
$\prod_k (1 + (t/a_k)^{b_k})^{c_k}$. Are there more natural generalizations?

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize any distribution $F(x;\eta)$ by adding parameters $\theta$ through the probability integral transform:

$$S(x;\eta,\theta)= P[F(x;\eta);\theta],$$

where $F(x;\eta)$ is the initial cdf, and $P:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a distribution with parameter $\theta$. If $P$ is the uniform distribution, then $S=F$. Popular choices of $P$ are the Beta distribution, or the Kumaraswamy distribution.

In terms of the density function

$$s(x;\eta,\theta)= p[F(x;\eta);\theta]f(x;\eta),$$
where $p$ is the pdf associated to $P$. Ideally, when you add parameters to a distribution, you would like them to have separate roles, and to avoid adding redundant parameters that may make your model unidentifiable.

See:

> Ferreira, J. T. S., & Steel, M. F. (2006). [A constructive representation of univariate skewed distributions](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214505000001212). Journal of the American Statistical Association.

Comment: It's a good idea to give a full citation rather than just a link (ie author names, year, title etc) as you would in the references section of a manuscript. That way it isn't a problem if the link location changes at some point in the future

Comment: @Silverfish Thanks for letting me know about this rule. Let me change it.

Comment: Thanks! Links are good but best accompanied by a citation - we hope that people will still read our answers for years to come, and our site has a major problem with "link rot" in our older answers. Full citations in addition to a link tend to "age-proof" our content better, and potentially allow the link to be updated later by future users if the location ever moves.